# Selenium Python unable to go to site in Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time, sys, datetime, calendar, os



browser = webdriver.Firefox()
loginURL = "some URL"
browser.get(loginURL)
```

The browser window opens but then it does nothing (blank white page). Seems like this used to work and now it's not. Why not?

Comment: Are you really passing the string `some URL` to `browser.get()`?

Comment: No, in practice it's a real formed URL

Comment: Ok, do you see any errors on the console?

Comment: What selenium package and firefox versions are you using?

Comment: Firefox version 31.0, Selenium version I am not sure how to check

Comment: Either run `pip freeze` (if you are using `pip`), or run `import selenium; print selenium.__version__`.

Comment: 2.32.0 is the Selenium version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your `selenium` package to the latest (currently, 2.42.1) version:

```
pip install selenium --upgrade
```

Note, that it is not a shot in the dark - I've reproduced the problem and upgrading helped to solve the issue.

Comment: Awesome, that did solve the issue. Thank you! (I can accept in 5)

Comment: @DoubleBass thank you for the quick qa session - it helped to help faster.